# Клонирование и сохранение объектов из другого контекста C#

Tags: c#, классы, entity-framework, context

У меня есть объект, который я получил из БД, мне нужно скопировать его, изменить некоторые свойства и сохранить в БД новый объект с измененными свойствами.

Чтоб его клонировать я использую метод `MemberwiseClone()`, получаю копию, изменяю свойства, а когда пытаюсь сохранить в БД выдает ошибку:

> An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext

Если я не буду клонировать объект, а просто создам новый (`var myObject = new MyClass()`) и пропишу все свойства при создании, то все будет ОК.

**Возможно  неправильно клонирую объект? Как правильно сохранять новый объект, чтоб не было такой ошибки?**

Comment: Попробуйте при селекте обьекта использовать метод AsNoTracking(). Что-то типа этого context.Staff.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

Comment: @Lightness, к сожалению, такой вариант не подходит

Comment: посмотрите тут, может тут есть ваше решение https://stevemichelotti.com/attach-an-entity-that-is-not-new-perhaps-having-been-loaded-from-another-datacontext/ тут https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4afff02d-51df-41fe-80b8-a19feaa9b2a7/an-attempt-has-been-made-to-attach-or-add-an-entity-that-is-not-new-perhaps-having-been-loaded-from?forum=linqtosql и тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549496/an-attempt-has-been-made-to-attach-or-add-an-entity-that-is-not-new-perhaps-hav

Comment: Нужно в склонированном объекте изменить первичный ключ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я уже пробовал, не помогает, ошибка та же. Если ключ не менять, то будет ошибка, что элемент уже существует.